# Sympy differentiation, equation is in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a function that is updated -- I'm optimizing using the method of newton and steepest.
I'm new to sympy, and hoping to get some quick clarification.

```
x1,x2 = sym.symbols('x1 x2')
y = 2*x1 + 3*x2**2 + sym.exp(2*x1**2 + x2**2)
gy1 = sym.diff(y,x1)
gy2 = sym.diff(y,x2)

grad1 = sym.lambdify([x1,x2],gy1)(x[0],x[1])
grad2 = sym.lambdify([x1,x2],gy2)(x[0],x[1])
d = np.array([-1*grad1,-1*grad2])

l = sym.symbols('l')

theta = 2*(x[0]+l*d[0]) + 3*(x[1]+l*d[1])**2 + sym.exp(2*(x[0]+l*d[0])**2 + (x[1]+l*d[1])**2)

theta_p = sym.diff(theta,l)
```

my function, `y` is updated as follow: `f(x_n) --> f(x_n + lambda*d_n)` -- call this `theta(lambda)`

I've updated as above `('theta' function)`, and when printed to screen, it gives a numpy array:

```
array([-63.1124487914452*l + 2 + exp([1991.5905962264*(0.0316894691665188 - l)**2])],
      dtype=object)
```

That is the equation I need, but now I want to differentiate it with respect to l, my lambda.  But sympy doesn't work like this.

When I run

```
sym.diff(theta,l)
```

I get this output:

```
AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_coeff_Mul'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: small caps L: `l` is a poor choice of variable name - it reads like the number one: `1`

Comment: yes, that's a true statement.

Comment: What's the type of theta[0]?

Comment: why are you mixing sympy and  numpy?

Comment: because I don't know any better yet?

Comment: What is `x` (as used in `x[1], x[2]`)?   Is it a list or array like `x=[1,2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sym.diff(theta[0], l)` and `sym.diff(theta[1], l)`

For some reason you end up with a ndarray containing objects that are sympy expressions. Print the type of each element to confirm.

Oh, there are nested ndarray expressions. You need to review what you are passing to theta.

You should end up with:

```
-63.1124487914452*l + 2 + exp(1991.5905962264*(0.0316894691665188 - l)**2)
```

instead of

```
array([-63.1124487914452*l + 2 + exp([1991.5905962264*(0.0316894691665188 - l)**2])],
  dtype=object)
```

Replace x[0] and x[1] with symbols in theta, then diff, lambdify and evaluate with x[0] and x[1]

Comment: Yes, I did, and I still get the same problem.

Comment: Replacing x[0] and x[1] with symbols does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If `xx` (your unspecified `x`) is (2,1) array:

```
In [153]: xx = np.array([[1],[1]])                                                                     

In [154]: grad1 = sym.lambdify([x1,x2],gy1)(xx[0],xx[1]) 
     ...: grad2 = sym.lambdify([x1,x2],gy2)(xx[0],xx[1]) 
     ...: d = np.array([-1*grad1,-1*grad2])                                                            

In [155]: d                                                                                            
Out[155]: 
array([[-82.34214769],
       [-46.17107385]])

In [156]: theta = 2*(xx[0]+l*d[0]) + 3*(xx[1]+l*d[1])**2 + sym.exp(2*(xx[0]+l*d[0])**2 + (xx[1]+l*d[1])
     ...: **2)                                                                                         

In [157]: theta                                                                                        
Out[157]: 
array([-164.684295385501*l + 6395.30418038233*(0.0216585822397654 - l)**2 + 2 + exp([13560.4585733095*(0.0121444488396316 - l)**2 + 2131.76806012744*(0.0216585822397654 - l)**2])],
      dtype=object)
```

If instead it is (2,) or a simple list

```
In [158]: xx = np.array([1,1])     # [1,1]                                                                    
...
In [160]: d                                                                                            
Out[160]: array([-82.34214769, -46.17107385])
```

and `theta` is then a simple `sympy` expression, not an object array containing an expression.  Then `theta_p` evaluates fine.

We can evaluate `gy1` at specific `x1`,`x2` with `evalf` instead of `lambdify`:

```
In [174]: xsub = {x1:1, x2:1}                                                                              
In [175]: d = [-1*gy1.evalf(subs=xsub), -1*gy2.evalf(subs=xsub)]                                       
In [176]: d                                                                                            
Out[176]: [-82.3421476927507, -46.1710738463753]
```